# How to change particular row wise column value in angularjs ui grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to change the value in a particular row wise column value in ui grid i.e., from Inactive to active status

I have a table in ui grid like

```
ID  Name     Status
1   India    Active
2   Germany  Inactive
3   France   Active
4   Italy    Active
5   Canada   Inactive
```

My grid code

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field : 'name',
            displayName : 'Name',
            width : '25%',
            enableColumnMenu : false,
            sort : {
                direction : uiGridConstants.ASC
            },
            cellTemplate : '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ng-controller="NameController"><a ng-click="editPop({{row.entity}})">{{COL_FIELD}}</a></div>'
        }, {
            field : 'status',
            displayName : 'Status',
            width : '25%',
            enableColumnMenu : false,
            cellTemplate: '<div ng-controller="StatusController" ng-if=\"row.entity.status == \'Active\'\" ><img src=\'assets/img/on.png\' /><a ng-click="checkStatusDepend(row.entity.id,row.entity.name,row.entity.status)">Active</a></div>'+
              '<div ng-controller="StatusController" ng-if=\"row.entity.status == \'Inactive\'\" ><img src=\'assets/img/off.png\' /><a ng-click="checkStatusDepend(row.entity.id,row.entity.name,row.entity.status)">Inactive</a></div>'
        }
    ],
    data: 'myData'
};
```

For calling this grid

```
getPage();
var getPage = function(obj) {
    object.charge({}, function(list){
        $scope.myData = list.data;  
    });
};
```

I am getting the list in myData so it is displayed in ui grid table.

I am updating the status in status controller

```
$rootScope.$emit("statusUpdateCall",id);
```

and for changing the value in another controller

```
$rootScope.$on('statusUpdateCall', function(events, args){
    getPage();
});
```

I want to change for `ID no 2 status` `Inactive to Active`, in backend using rest spring i am updating in database but in frontend i need to change it to Active.

Currently i load the data from beginning.

I have gone through the angularjs ui grid tutorial using splice it removes particular row and add a new row with new changed data.

But without splice is there any other options are there to update particular column value?

Comment: Try `angular.copy(list.data, $scope.myData)`